# BlackBerry - line not showing

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-editfield

I am having a problem with `EditField`.
I have created an `EditField` using this code under a "HorizontalFieldManager".

```
EditField nameEditLabel = new EditField (EditField.FOCUSABLE 
    | EditField.NO_NEWLINE | EditField.FIELD_RIGHT);
nameEditLabel.setMaxSize(25);
nameEditLabel.setMargin(50, 0, 0, 80);
horizontalFldManager.add(nameEditLabel);
```

Problem now is, On the screen, it doesn't show the line of the field. Something like, basically a Field contain "Name: ----------------------" such line in other platform controls, which is not showing here on the screen. What is the problem here? Is it default in API support? If no, how do i resolve it?

Note: This line is getting created only when i write something on the field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have this "----" in case EditField is empty, extend it to implement check value logic:

```
class LabelFieldEmpty extends EditField {
 String mEmptyText = "";

 public LabelFieldEmpty(long style) {
  super(style);
 }

 public void setEmptyText(String emptyText) {
  mEmptyText = emptyText;
 }

 public String getEmptyText() {
  return mEmptyText;
 }

 protected boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) {
  if (null != mEmptyText)
   if (getText().equalsIgnoreCase(mEmptyText)) {
    setText(String.valueOf(key));
    return true;
   }
  return super.keyChar(key, status, time);
 }

 protected void fieldChangeNotify(int context) {
  if (null != mEmptyText)
   if (!getText().equalsIgnoreCase(mEmptyText))
    if (getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
     setText(mEmptyText);
     setCursorPosition(0);
    }
  super.fieldChangeNotify(context);
 }
}
```

Example of use:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {

 public Scr() {
  String label = "Name:";
  String empty = "-------------------------";
  int maxChars = 25;
  long style = EditField.FOCUSABLE | EditField.NO_NEWLINE
    | EditField.FIELD_RIGHT;
  LabelFieldEmpty nameEdit = new LabelFieldEmpty(style);
  nameEdit.setLabel(label);
  nameEdit.setMaxSize(maxChars);
  nameEdit.setMargin(50, 0, 0, 80);
  nameEdit.setEmptyText(empty);
  add(nameEdit);
 }
}
```